# Как реализовать проверку полей через js перед отправкой?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такая форма с обработчиком отправки заявки на почту. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать проверку полей на заполнение а поле почты соответственно на присутствие @ в адресе? Нужно по типу required только через jquery (в сафари required не работает).

```js
document.getElementById('feedback-form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    f = this;
  evt.preventDefault();
  http.open("POST", "http://ravtest1.site88.net/pro-stroy/contacts.php", true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.send("nameFF=" + f.nameFF.value + "&phone=" + f.phone.value + "&contactFF=" + f.contactFF.value + "&messageFF=" + f.messageFF.value);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      $('.msg-form').html("Спасибо за обращение! Мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время.");
      f.messageFF.removeAttribute('value'); // очистить поле сообщения (две строки)
      f.messageFF.value = '';
    }
  }
  http.onerror = function() {
    $('.msg-form').html("Извините, данные не были переданы");
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="msg-form"></div>
<form method="POST" id="feedback-form">
  <div class="box-input">
    <label for="name">Введите имя</label>
    <input type="text" name="nameFF" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="box-input">
    <label for="email">Введите e-mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="contactFF" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="box-input">
    <label for="phone">Введите контактный телефон</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone">
  </div>
  <div class="box-input">
    <label for="vopr">Задайте вопрос</label>
    <input type="text" name="messageFF" id="vopr">
  </div>
  <div class="box-button">
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: >в сафари required не работает

Answer (score 1):

```
function cheсk_str(str) {
        if (str.length>0)
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Это проверка на пустоту строки

```
  function chek_mail(str) {
        if (str.indexOf('@')>0)
        {
            if ((str.indexOf('.',str.indexOf('@'))>0)&&(str.indexOf('.',str.indexOf('@')-str.indexOf('@')>1))){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Это проверка e-mail, смысл: ищем @, если есть проверяем наличие . после @, и проверяем чтобы между . и @ были какие-либо символы. 
Организовать это все надо до строки http.send()

```
     document.getElementById('feedback-form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
    if (check_str(f.nameFF.value) && check_str(f.phone.value) && check_str(f.messageFF.value) && chek_mail(f.contactFF.value))
{
          var http = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            f = this;
          evt.preventDefault();
          http.open("POST", "http://ravtest1.site88.net/pro-stroy/contacts.php", true);
          http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          http.send("nameFF=" + f.nameFF.value + "&phone=" + f.phone.value + "&contactFF=" + f.contactFF.value + "&messageFF=" + f.messageFF.value);
          http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
              $('.msg-form').html("Спасибо за обращение! Мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время.");
              f.messageFF.removeAttribute('value'); // очистить поле сообщения (две строки)
              f.messageFF.value = '';
            }
          }
          http.onerror = function() {
            $('.msg-form').html("Извините, данные не были переданы");
          }
        }} else{
$('.msg-form').html("Вы ввели что-то не так");
}
, false);

        function cheсk_str(str) {
                if (str.length>0)
                {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        function chek_mail(str) {
                if (str.indexOf('@')>0)
                {
                    if ((str.indexOf('.',str.indexOf('@'))>0)&&(str.indexOf('.',str.indexOf('@')-str.indexOf('@')>1))){
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: А можете написать, пожалуйста, на примере одного поля с моим кодом?